# Error message while copy file from LocalFile to hdfs

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, cloudera, hadoop2

I tried to copy file from local to 
hdfs. Using the command 
hadoop dfs -copyFromLocal in/ /user/hduser/hadoop

The following error message shown. Please help to find the problem.

DEPRECATED: Use of this script to execute hdfs command is deprecated.
Instead use the hdfs command for it.

```
15/02/02 19:22:23 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: DataStreamer Exception
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): File /user/hduser/hadoop._COPYING_ could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 0 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.chooseTarget4NewBlock(BlockManager.java:1549)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:3200)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:641)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:482)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:619)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:962)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2039)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2035)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2033)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1468)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1399)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:232)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:399)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:187)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.locateFollowingBlock(DFSOutputStream.java:1532)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSOutputStream.java:1349)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:588)
copyFromLocal: File /user/hduser/hadoop._COPYING_ could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 0 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation.
```

My hdfs-site.xml

```
<property>
       <name>dfs.replication</name>
       <value>1</value>
     </property>
     <property>
       <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
       <value>file:/home/hduser/mydata/hdfs/namenode</value>
     </property>
     <property>
       <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
       <value>file:/home/hduser/mydata/hdfs/datanode</value>
     </property>
```

jps

```
12805 NameNode
13276 ResourceManager
13398 NodeManager
13081 SecondaryNameNode
14129 Jps
```

Comment: It looks as though your namenode is down, so you might want to look into that. Does restarting your cluster help? Can you execute any other HDFS commands?

Comment: It seems like there are no datanodes running in the cluster, if they are running make sure they could talk to the namenode.

Comment: other hdfs commands like hadoop fs -ls,-mkdir ,-rm -r are working...  I used hadoop dfsadmin -report command                           'DEPRECATED: Use of this script to execute hdfs command is deprecated.
Instead use the hdfs command for it.

Configured Capacity: 0 (0 B)
Present Capacity: 0 (0 B)
DFS Remaining: 0 (0 B)
DFS Used: 0 (0 B)
DFS Used%: NaN%
Under replicated blocks: 0
Blocks with corrupt replicas: 0
Missing blocks: 0

-------------------------------------------------'
how can i test datanode is running or not? Is there commands to run datanode?

Answer (score 0):

The following steps should fix the issue. **However, you may lose data.**

- Stop Hadoop :

  - sbin/stop-dfs.sh
  - sbin/stop.yarn.sh
- Delete NameNode & DataNode:

  - hdfs dfs -rm -r /mydata/hdfs/namenode
  - hdfs dfs -rm -r /mydata/hdfs/datanodenode
- Format NameNode

  - hdfs namenode -format
- Start NameNode, Datanodes & YARN

  - sbin/start-dfs.sh
  - sbin/start-yarn.sh

Answer (score 0):

> We can see that you have missing `NameNode` and `DataNode` from jps
>   output.

First stop hadoop on hadoop directory

```
cd /usr/local/hadoop/sbin
stop-all.sh
```

Then remove the contents of NameNode and DataNode

```
rm -rf /usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs/namenode/*
rm -rf /usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs/datanode/*
```

format NameNode

```
hadoop namenode -format
```

start all over again

```
start-all.sh
```